# Error C2106: '=' left operand must be l-value

Tags: c, printf

I am making a program for school (my class is Intro to C) and we have to create a letter guessing game. At this stage, I am just trying to open the file `input.txt` and print `4 letters` on to the screen so I know it is connecting to the file. When I build it without the `printf` to print 4 letters onto the screen, it works fine, but when i add the `printf`, it gives me errors like:

```
error C2106: '=' left operand must be l-value
IntelliSense: expression must be a modifiable lvalue
warning C4047: '=' : 'int(_cdecl*)(constant char*,...)' differs 
in levels of indirection from 'int'
```

Can anyone help?

```
int main()
{
    //declare additional variables
    int gamesToPlay = 4, i = 0;
    FILE *inptr;
    int letter, win = 0, lose = 0;

    //display instructions
    //open file
    //get number of games to play
    scanf("%d", &gamesToPlay);
    inptr = fopen ("input.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; i < gamesToPlay; i++)
    {
        //get a letter from file
        //Play one game (Call PlayOneRound function)
        //tell the player if they won or lost
        fscanf(inptr, " %c", &letter);
        printf = letter;
        //win = PLayOneRound(letter);
    }

    //close file
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this `printf = letter;` doesn't look good.

Comment: `scanf` with `%c` into an `int` isn't looking so hot right now either. [That should be a `char`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Comment: Start indenting your code properly now.  It will save you headaches throughout the whole class term.

Answer (score 3):

The type of the variable `letter` should be `char`
And you can't use `printf = letter;`.  The compiler expects `printf` to be a variable in this statement.  Instead use `printf("%c", letter);`

Answer (score 1):

So, what I have done below is fix some of the things, taking into account some user-comments. Firstly, you need to have a better grasp of how printf statement work and how variables are called within them. Look at the first four lines of `main()` to see how I have neatened up and corrected your variable declarations; most importantly of those is the change of `letter` from `int` to `char`. To me, your first `scanf()` statement seemed superfluous for what you were doing, however you may be using it in future, if you do make sure to use `%d` for reading in an `int`.

I also used the appropriate statement to close the file `fclose()`, read up on that.
I left most of your comments in.

Overall, well done on giving it a go, you are on the right track. Keep up the learning, and make sure to read up some more to iron out the creases and finish this program. Nearly there!

```
int main()
{
 //declare additional variables
 int gamesToPlay = 4;
 int win = 0, lose = 0;
 char letter;

 FILE *inptr;                                        | <---- putting these two together is good practice
 inptr = fopen ("input.txt", "r");                   | <---- 

 for (int i = 0; i < gamesToPlay; i++)
   {
     //get a letter from file
     //Play one game (Call PlayOneRound function)
     //tell the player if they won or lost
     fscanf(inptr, "%c", &letter);
     printf("%c\n", letter);                  <----- it is very important you know how to use printf correctly
     //win = PLayOneRound(letter);
   }

    //close file
    fclose(inptr);                          <---- closing a file is important

    return 0;
}
```